# Determine if CodeIgniter update query successfully affected any rows

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-update, rows-affected

How do I tell when a MySQL UPDATE was successful versus actually updated data?

**Example:**

```
TABLE
id    city_name
1     Union
2     Marthasville
```

If I run the following:

```
$data = array('city_name', 'Marthasville');

//update record 2 from Marthasville to the same thing, Marthasville. 
$this->db->where('id', 2);
$this->db->update('table', $data);

if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
{
    //I need it to return TRUE when the MySQL was successful even if nothing was actually updated.
    return TRUE;
}else{
    return FALSE;
}
```

This will return `TRUE` every time the UPDATE statement is successful, but FALSE when no rows were actually updated.

I need it to return `TRUE` every time the UPDATE statement was successfully executed even if it doesn't actually change any records.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Have a look at [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

It should tell you if anything was actually updated as opposed to nothing was successfully updated resulting in a return of true.

php.net says:

> mysql_affected_rows()
>
> Returns the number of affected rows on success, and -1 if the last
>   query failed.

You could use the following to achieve your desired results:

```
if($this->db->affected_rows() >= 0){ }
```

Comment: I just updated my question again to more clearly state the issue I am having with using mysql_affected_rows(). Wish I wouldn't have posted my question so soon :S

Comment: I believe JLeafgle's answer was still correct. mysql_affected_rows will return -1 if the last query failed, otherwise will return >= 0. Assuming that's what you're after, then just change your if statement to... "if($this->db->affected_rows() >= 0)"

Comment: You are correct @Jon Stirling. I updated Jleagle's answer to reflect your suggestion, however I can't approve the edit so if someone else could, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: If this can be useful for any, with the new mysqli extension the parentheses dissappear, so it would be $db->affected_rows; to get the number of rows updated (you will get a 500 Error if you write the () ).

Comment: Note that if the value to be updated with isn't compatible with the column property (e.g. updating an integer column with a string), affected_rows() will still give a positive result (as the column will be updated, but not with the value requested). You need to also check for any warnings e.g. using mysqli_warning_count(db)==0.

Answer (score 18):

Then you would use [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/mysql_query):

> SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query()
>   returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

Simple like this:

```
$result = $this->db->update('table', $data);

if($result)
{
     //without error even no row updated
} else {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your code would work for my situation, however, Jleagle's answer works a little better in my code.

Comment: Does this also apply to PDO object in later versions of PHP?