# Unable to insert data in mysql table via php

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to inset data into mysql table. What is wrong with my code?
Here is the php code i have used. I am getting no response on submission.
The php is used in the same page the html form is included so, my attributes are  action="" and method="post". Please help. 
`enter code here`

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require_once 'dbconnect.php';

    // if session is not set this will redirect to login page
    if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
        header("Location: index.html");
        exit;
    }
    // select loggedin users detail
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);


    if ( isset($_POST['sub']) ) {

        // clean user inputs to prevent sql injections
        $name1 = $_POST['name1'];
        $name2 = $_POST['name2'];
        $name3 = $_POST['name3'];
        $name4 = $_POST['name4'];
        $name5 = $_POST['name5'];
        $name6 = $_POST['name6'];
        $name7 = $_POST['name7'];
        $name8 = $_POST['name8'];
        $name9 = $_POST['name9'];


        if( !$error ) {

            $query = "INSERT INTO users(name1,name2,name3,name4,name5,name6,name7,name8,name9) VALUES('$name1','$name2','$name3','$name4','$name5','$name6','$name7','$name8','$name9') WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user'];
            $res = mysql_query($query);

            if ($res) {
                $errTyp = "success";
                $errMSG = "Successfully registered, you may login now";
                unset($name1);

            } else {
                $errTyp = "danger";
                $errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later...";   
            }
            }
}
?>
```

Comment: Just a note: you are not "cleaning" anything and doing nothing to stop SQL injections. Use parameters immediately.

Comment: I second the first comment - but if you are learning and this isn't going to production...first thing that jumped out at me is the WHERE after an INSERT. How do you specify criteria for something that doesn't exist? You would use WHERE for an UPDATE not INSERT

Comment: I know i have simplified the code just for understanding. But still its not working

Comment: Oops, you are right @SamiKuhmonen. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is $error parameter contain in if statement,

Answer (score 0):

As Alex.Barylski pointed out in a comment, an INSERT statement creates a new row, so you cannot use a WHERE clause (which is used to examine an existing row...). If you want to update a row which already exists, use the following instead of your INSERT statement:

```
     $query = 'UPDATE users SET name1 = "$name1", name2 = "$name2", name3 = "$name3" WHERE userId=' . $_SESSION['user'];
```

Note also that you can use mysql_affected_rows() to check whether your UPDATE query was successful, see this question: [How do I tell when a MySQL UPDATE was successful versus actually updated data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368225/how-do-i-tell-when-a-mysql-update-was-successful-versus-actually-updated-data)